# A task inside my windows task scheduler will cause my server to stop responding

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler, ps1

I have the following `AppPoolActivation.ps1` file, to call a URL :-

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("https://IPADDRESS***/")
$response = $request.GetResponse()
$response.Close()
```

and I wrote the following `app.bat` file to call the above `AppPoolActivation.ps1` file:-

```
"%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Command Start-Process "$PSHOME\powershell.exe" -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "'-NoExit %~dp0\AppPoolActivation.ps1'
```

Then inside my windows server 2012  windows tasks scheduler , I define a Daily task which run each 15 minutes for a duration of 1 day, so mainly it will always run each 15 minutes, and I define this task to call the .bat file, as follow:-

[image]

[image]

now when I first define the task it worked well for around 5 hours, but I have noted that after 10-12 hours the server will be very slow till it stop responding, now I check the task manager on the server and I find that there will be many instances of windows power shell & Console windows host running, as follow:-

[image]

so can anyone advice how I can overcome this problem ? I mean why there will be many instances of windows power shell & Console windows host running ? and is there a way to prevent this from happening and prevent my server to became very slow due to the task schedule ? baring in mind that I have never face any problem on this server for around many years ago ,, the problem started when I create this schedule task...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Command Start-Process "$PSHOME\powershell.exe" -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "'-NoExit %~dp0\AppPoolActivation.ps1'
```

So you have a batch file, which starts powershell instance, which starts another powershell instance as Administrator, which executes `AppPoolActivation.ps1` script?

Why wouldn't you just put `PowerShell.exe` in <kbd>Program/Script</kbd> field in <kbd>Task Properties</kbd> and use `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\T\AppPoolActivation.ps1` as argument? I doubt that you need to run PowerShell as admin to make web request. And if this issue would still persist, this will make debugging it way easier.

Comment: I tried your approach at the beginning to call the .ps1 directly from the task, but it never succeed I think the problem is related to a policy that we can not run PowerShell scripts ,,,now what I did I modify the current .bat file and I remove the "-NoExit" from it, and now I can not see repeated processes inside my task manager,, seems -NoExit  will not end the process once the powershell script ends, I thought -NoExit  will prevent the process from being ended during the execution, but seems it mean to never end the process even after it is being completed..

Comment: @JohnJohn You can bypass execution policy with from Task Manager too. See updated answer. `"seems -NoExit will not end the process once the powershell script ends"` - yep, see [PowerShell.exe Command-Line Help](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx).